# How to lock a database row with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, locking

In the following code snippet, the whole table is locked instead of a single row:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void myInsertMethod(MyEntity myEntity) {

         
    /*1 this doesn't works*/
         manager.lock(myEntity,LockModeType.READ);
         manager.persist(myEntity);
    
    /* and this works but I dont know is it what i want or not...*/
        manager.persist(myEntity);
        manager.lock(myEntity,LockModeType.READ);
         
    }
```

I think that the correct code will be the following, but it doesn't work

```
/*lock entire table for select*/
manager.lock(MyEntity.class.LockModeType.READ);
/* and after locking table persist code */
manager.persist(myEntity);
```

Please tell me how I can do this job and suggest me a good article for learning this issue.

Comment: Why do you need to lock entire table ?

Comment: because, when select query is run on this table, not get data while persist request is sent on server

Comment: You should let your RDBMS worry about whether a table or row lock is required. Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle database

Comment: my select method on this table is important , if someone inserts data, the select will be different. and i what table was locked if persist request is sent...

Answer (score 2):

The [LockModeType.READ is equals to OPTIMISTIC](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/), meaning Hibernate tries to verify the optimistically locked entity version before transaction completion.

Aside from the [possible race condition](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-does-optimistic-lock-mode-work/), this won't help you too much. In your case, the entity [acquires an implicit lock](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/) when the [flush operation issues an INSERT statement](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/).

Because entities have unique PRIMARY KEYS, you shouldn't even care too much about locking the rows, since you can't have two transactions inserting the same row. The concurrency control is more suitable for UPDATE/DELETE statements, and even then, you don't need to lock an entire table (just the records you want to change).